# Get the selected value of a DropDownList. Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to populate a DropDownList and to get the selected value when I submit the form:

Here is my model :

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        this.Clients = new List<Client>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

My Controllers :

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Action()
    {
        var books = GetBooks();
        ViewBag.Books = new SelectList(books);
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(Book book)
    {
        if (ValidateFields()
        {
            var data = GetDatasAboutBookSelected(book);
            ViewBag.Data = data;
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My Form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Journaux","Company"))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("book", (SelectList)ViewBag.Books)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

When I click, the parameter 'book' in the Action is always null.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In HTML a dropdown box sends only simple scalar values. In your case that would be the id of the selected book:

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedBookId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Books)
```

and then adapt your controller action so that you will retrieve the book from the id that gets passed to your controller action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(string selectedBookId)
{
    if (ValidateFields()
    {
        Book book = FetchYourBookFromTheId(selectedBookId);
        var data = GetDatasAboutBookSelected(book);
        ViewBag.Data = data;
        return View();
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I have another question about that. In fact, the DropDownList selected value returns the value of the `ToString()` method of `Book` .
So I have to put the Ids in my DropDownList, but I would like the list to display the title and the selected value to be the Id.
Is there a way to do that?

For now, I use this way : the `ToString()` method returns "Id - Title"  and I use `SubString()` to keep only the Id.
But I would like the DropDownList to display only the Title without the Id.

Comment: The `SelectList` class that you are passing to the DropDown is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` where `SelectListItem` has 2 properties: `Value` and `Text`. You could set the `Value` to the `Id` of your Book instance and the `Text` to whatever format you want.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, It's tremendous! That is what I would like to do! You are the wizard:).

Answer (score 2):

You can use DropDownListFor as below, It so simpler

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, new SelectList(Model.Books,"Id","Name","1"))
```

(You need a strongly typed view for this -- View bag is not suitable for large lists)

```
   public ActionResult Action(Book model)
   {
        if (ValidateFields()
        {
            var Id = model.Id;
        ...
```

I think this is simpler to use.