# how to set the selected value in dropdownlist mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-select

I have a dropdown in `View`

```
@Html.DropDownList("GenderAllowed", (SelectList)ViewBag.LocGenederAllowedList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and I am sending list of dropdown through `ViewBag`, and through model I am sending value that need to be selected in the dropdown.

But the value in dropdown is not selected.

My Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditVendorLocation(int VendorLocationID)
    {
        VendorLocationHandler obj = new VendorLocationHandler();
        LocationGrid objLoc = new LocationGrid();
        FillGenederAllowed(objLoc);
        objLoc = obj.GetVendorLocationForAdmin(VendorLocationID);

        return View(objLoc);
    }
```

Function for Viewbag

```
public void FillGenederAllowed(LocationGrid V)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> LocGenederAllowed = EnumHelper.GetGenderStates();
    SelectList LocGenederAllowedList = new SelectList(LocGenederAllowed, "key", "value");
    ViewBag.LocGenederAllowedList = LocGenederAllowedList;
}
```

Comment: Model is a list of values. Did you set any of them as `Selected = true`?

Comment: Please refer below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881575/get-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropdownlist set selected value in MVC3 Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807256/dropdownlist-set-selected-value-in-mvc3-razor)

Comment: Just set the value of property `GenderAllowed` to match the value of one of your options and it will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectListItems`you are passing to the DropDownList have a property `Selected`. In your ViewModel, set this to true for the item that should be selected initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your controller action like following. Hope it helps.

```
ViewBag.LocGenederAllowedList = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name", selectedValue);
```

dot net fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PFlqei

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://bit.ly/1PWwTba) class.
All you need to do is create instances of them and set the `Selected` property to true for the item you want to be initially selected:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(...)
{
    var selectItems = Repository.SomeDomainModelObjectCollection
      .Select(x => new SelectListItem {
        Text = x.SomeProperty,
        Value = x.SomeOtherProperty,
        Selected = ShoudBeSelected(x)
    });
    ViewBag.SelectListItems = selectItems;
    // more code
    var model = ...; // create your model
    return View(model);
}
```

You will need this overload of `Html.DropDownListFor(...)` in order to use [this](http://bit.ly/1PWwTba).

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your controller

```
   ViewBag.LocGenederAllowedList = 
       new SelectList(db.SomeValues, "Value", "Text",selectedValue);
```

And in your view

```
            @Html.DropDownList("GenderAllowed", 
         (SelectList)ViewBag.LocGenederAllowedList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: This is not workingSelectList LocGenederAllowedList = new SelectList(LocGenederAllowed, "key", "value", GenderAllow);